# How to search by an attribute of another attribute with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have PlaceDTO and CategoryDTO, which connect in PlaceCategoryDTO(many to many).

```
public class PlaceCategoryDTO implements Serializable{

private Long id;
private Long categoryID;
private Long placeID;
private CategoryDTO category;
private PlaceDTO place;
//getters and setters
}
```

I have PlaceCategoryDAO and i want to search by two attributes. One is the categoryID and the other is an attribute of PlaceDTO(region). For searching by categoryID and placeID i have this method in PlaceCategoryDAO:

```
public class PlaceCategoryDAO extends GenericHibernateDAO<PlaceCategoryDTO,Long>{
  public  List<PlaceCategoryDTO> findByParameters(Long placeID, Long categoryID)
    {
      List<Criterion> criteria = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
      if (placeID != null)
        {
          criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("placeID",placeID));  
        }
      if (categoryID != null)
        {
          criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("categoryID",categoryID));  
        }
      return findByCriteria(criteria);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if i can search by place.region instead of placeID.

Comment: On a related note, what do `placeID` and `categoryID` signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations). Just add another criterion and your restriction.